# How to find words with more than 3 characters between 2 other words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have 2 sentences:

```
Today one dog will eat 2 kg of meats more than a cat
Human always prefer dog and cat
```

With the help of regex:

1. I would like to find sentences that have dog and cat together without human
2. I need also to have words between dog and cat which have more than 3 characters in the sentence where we can't find human

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the string you're matching contains one sentence:

```
"^(?!.*human)(?=.*dog)(?=.*cat)"
```

will match if the string contains `dog` and `cat` but not `human`.

For your second question (finding all words of more than two (!) characters between `dog` and `cat`, you need two steps (at least in Java):

First, find the part of the string between `dog` and `cat` using the regex

```
"(?<=dog).*(?=cat)"
```

Then, on the match result, use the regex `"\\w{3,}"` to find all alphanumeric words of length 3 or more.

Comment: You're doing 3 or more. The requirement is more (minimum 4), unless the question is badly phrased.

Comment: I agreed with the first part of answer but it doesn't work with the second part where I can't find words with more than 3 characters only.

Comment: You said "more than 3 characters", not "words with more than 3 characters" in your question. `"cat is dog"` matches because `" is "` contains 4 characters. Is that the problem? Then just use `{5,}` instead of `{4,}` (or rephrase your question. Should `"cat chases a dog"` match? There is one word with more than 3 and one with less than 3 characters between `cat` and `dog`).

Comment: What I need is to find words between dog and cat having 3 or more characters. Sorry for my bad english. I think you understand me

Comment: @user1985137: No, I don't think I fully understand. Should `dog chases a cat` match or not?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: In the sentence: "dog will eat 2 kg of meats more than a cat", I want to find *will, eat, meats, more and than*

Comment: Oh, so that's completely different from what you wrote in your question. I'm afraid you can only do that with the .NET regex engine. Which language are you using?